# How to integrate Outlook calendar for MS work account users using Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi, microsoft-graph-calendar, microsoft-oauth

I want to build a feature where I want to sync users outlook calendar with my app. Any event which users create/reschedule/delete from my app should reflect in users outlook calendars. First step for this however would be getting access token and refresh token for the users by authenticating them. How can I build APIs to authenticate users and get the token for further use.

I have checked there is MS-Graph API, which can be used in my use-case. But I'm unable to find resources regarding how to use this APIs from my spring boot application. Also, this is not regarding the login/signup flow. I have another login flow. I don't want users to login to my app via their outlook email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Enable your Java Spring Boot web app to sign in users and call Microsoft Graph with the Microsoft identity platform:

Overview:
This sample demonstrates a Java Spring Boot web app that signs in users and obtains an access token for calling Microsoft Graph. It uses the Azure AD Spring Boot Starter client library for Java for authentication, authorization, and token acquisition. It leverages Microsoft Graph SDK for Java to obtain data from Graph.

For more information: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-msal-java-samples/tree/main/4.%20Spring%20Framework%20Web%20App%20Tutorial/2-Authorization-I/call-graph#enable-your-java-spring-boot-web-app-to-sign-in-users-and-call-microsoft-graph-with-the-microsoft-identity-platform

Hope this helps.